Animation looks broken on Webkit based Browsers
I have this animation which works perfect fine on browsers like Chrome, but the moment I try it on Safari it looks broken and doesn't do what it is supposed to do.


.progressIndicator {
  stroke: red;
}

.progressIndicator svg {
  animation: crotate 1.5s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: crotate 1.5s linear infinite;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.progressIndicator circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 1, 200;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  animation: cdash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite 0s;
  -webkit-animation: cdash 1.5s ease-in-out infinite 0s;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 7.5px;
}

@keyframes crotate {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes crotate {
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes cdash {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 1, 200;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dasharray: 89, 200;
    stroke-dashoffset: -35;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 89, 200;
    stroke-dashoffset: -124;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes cdash {
  0% {
    stroke-dasharray: 1, 200;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  50% {
    stroke-dasharray: 89, 200;
    stroke-dashoffset: -35;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dasharray: 89, 200;
    stroke-dashoffset: -124;
  }
}
<div class="progressIndicator">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="20" />
  </svg>
</div>



If you have any additional questions, please let me know. I did everything in my knowledge to make this animation as Webkit compatible as possible, but I had no success so far.

For debugging questions please edit your question to include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it, i.e. you're missing the HTML code. See How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

@SyndRain I added the HTML code. Thanks for letting me know!

Please make the snippet more complete, where is progress-indicator, the color var setting and the second keyframes used? At the moment it doesn’t show us anything other than a circle when run.

@AHaworth the progress indicator is basically the main div that holds the loading circle. I corrected the HTML code. The color var is basically a white color I use on my website, it's not really relevant so I just set it as red.
I'm so sorry the post was a bit incomplete, I was in a rush and didn't have enough time to double check anything. I hope the changes make it easier to identify the problem now.

Thanks for the updated code. In what way is it not working on Safari?

@AHaworth After checking again, it seems like the first rotate animation works fine. The problem is with the 2nd one called dash, which doesn't seem to work at all.
